# How load a new page in the browser using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am a total beginner and what I want is to load a completely new page in the browser just by clicking a button. I tried something, but doesn't work. Here is the code.

NodeJS file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs= require('fs');


var htmlHome = "";
var htmlDemo = "";


htmlHome = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
htmlDemo = fs.readFileSync("demo.html");

//console.log(htmlHome.toString());

function onRequest(request, response)
{
    console.log("A user made a request" + request.url);
  if(request.url === "/")
  {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(htmlHome);
    response.end();
  }
  else if(request.url === "/demo.html")
  {
    console.log("DEMO")
    response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(htmlDemo);
    response.end();    
  }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80);
console.log("Server is running...")
```

Here is the file `index.html` that loads at the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "demo.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the `demo.html` that I want to load when I hit the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>This is demo file!/h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Everythings work except when I hit the button the new page doesnt come up. How to make so that when I hit the button the `demo.html` page to be loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just open a new browser page it will be simply `window.open` on the client side.

But if you want to get the content without reloading the page you need to not only send the request, but receive it's response and render it's proper part on the page.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a much simpler method. Instead of

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

just use a hyperlink:

```
<a href='demo.html'>Change Content</a>
```

This will user the browser's build in navigation functions.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the NodeJS "express" package is very good for serving static files directly from disk so you don't have to do all the file reads yourself.